# how record values in the android SQLite DB every 5 minutes?

Tags: java, android, sql, database

[image]

This is where I wanted to record, every second was being recorded. But I want data to be added every 5 minutes

Comment: You might want to make your question about one problem. Are you struggling with repeating logic every 5 minutes, running background tasks, using SQLite, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **RxJava** to accomplish this task in a couple of seconds.

and **use these dependencies:**

```
 implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'



 Disposable  disposable = Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .doOnNext(n -> YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME()).subscribe();
```

**REPLACE YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME with your function name**

When you need to stop this just use the below code:

```
 if (!disposable.isDisposed())
            disposable.dispose();
```

Comment: @Diponkar Kindly upvote the answer if you find it useful.